# How to create "abstract" module in Elixir or "virtual" functions?

Tags: elixir

I know I'm a little bit Ruby-ish or even Java-ish here but here's the case I encounter very often.

I want to define some general module (metaprogramming can be used) which will use some variables/function that will be specified in "children" modules (which will probably `use` this general module).

I imagine it like:

```
defmodule Parent do
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      def function do
        __MODULE__.other_function
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and later on:

```
defmodule Child do
  use Parent

  def other_function do
    # some real work
  end
end
```

I very often need to "abstract" some function and the best it would be by defining some module-variable `@var` accessible in "parent" module but I know that it doesn't work like that whatsoever.

Is there any way to call a function that will be defined in "including" module?

Comment: Consider exactly why you want to turn Elixir into OOP. This is the point of using functions not objects - to use them whetever you want. Just create module where you will have common functionality and use it anywhere you need, but don't go into inheritance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're on the right track. If you add a `@callback` to define the `spec` for the "abstract" function it would be better. I'll explain with a working example:

```
defmodule Fibonacci do
  @callback fib(number :: integer) :: integer

  defmacro __using__(_) do
      quote do
        @behaviour Fibonacci

        def fibonacci(n) when not is_integer(n), do: {:error, "Not integer"}
        def fibonacci(n) when n < 0, do: {:error, "Negative number"}
        def fibonacci(n), do: {:ok, __MODULE__.fib(n)}

        def fibonacci!(n) do
          case fibonacci(n) do
            {:error, reason} -> raise reason
            {:ok, n} -> n
          end
        end
      end
  end
end
```

Every module that uses `Fibonacci` will need to implement the callback function `fib/1`. Also every module that `use` the `Fibonacci` module will have the function `fibonacci/1` that handles errors and `fibonacci!/1` that raises errors.

So, let's implement `fib/1` with direct recursion:

```
defmodule Direct do
  use Fibonacci

  def fib(0), do: 0
  def fib(1), do: 1
  def fib(n), do: fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
end
```

And for tail recursion:

```
defmodule Tail do
  use Fibonacci

  def fib(0), do: 0
  def fib(1), do: 1
  def fib(n), do: fib(1, 1, n - 2)

  defp fib(_, value, 0), do: value
  defp fib(n_2, n_1, n), do: fib(n_1, n_2 + n_1, n - 1)
end
```

So in `iex` we can call the different implementations:

```
iex(1)> Direct.fibonacci(10)
{:ok, 55}
iex(2)> Tail.fibonacci!(10)
55
iex(3)> Tail.fibonacci!(-10)
** (RuntimeError) Negative number
```

Also, if you forget to define the `fib/1` function in your module, then the compiler will warn you about it:

```
defmodule Warning do
  use Fibonacci
end

* warning: undefined behaviour function fib/1 (for behaviour Fibonacci)
```

If you want to play with this code, just follow this link
http://elixirplayground.com?gist=606fe8c283443f03c7af08f85c888fe3

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

There is probably more than one way to do it depending on your exact use case. The simplest thing to do is to just use higher order functions and no metaprogramming at all.

```
defmodule Parent do
  def function(function_passed_as_variable) do
    function_passed_as_variable.()
  end
end

defmodule Child do
  def function do
    Parent.function(&other_function/1)
  end
  def other_function do
    #some real function
  end
end
```

I kept the names `Parent` and `Child` to refer to your code, but in this situation it doesn't fit.

To achieve polymorphism (one function doing different things depending on data), you could use pattern matching:

```
def function({:first_type, data}), do: data*2
def function({:second_type, data}), do: data+2
def function(data), do: data
```

There are also protocols which can be defined for different structs and other datatypes.

It might not be easy to choose the right pattern so feel free to comment on more specific example.

Comment: Thanks Tomek for your response. I was also thinking about passing a function name to `opts` in `use` to dynamically build "parent" function that will call this given function from a "child" module.

Comment: I think that is not necessary when you can pass the function directly.